# Assign different keycodes for two keys with same keycode

Tags: linux, keyboard, remapping

I have a Dell Latitude 3510. The problem is that currently two keys are redundant and they have the exact keycodes and scancodes as their counterparts (as described [Here](https://www.dell.com/community/Vostro/Dell-vostro-7590-calculator-keys-are-useless/td-p/7324426)).

Specifically, <kbd>F9</kbd> and <kbd>+</kbd> / <kbd>-</kbd> keys have the exact same function and also <kbd>CE</kbd> and <kbd>Del</kbd> key act the exact same.

Result of `evtest` command for <kbd>F9</kbd> and <kbd>+</kbd> / <kbd>-</kbd>:

```
^[[20~Event: time 1641717487.410492, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 43
Event: time 1641717487.410492, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 67 (KEY_F9), value 0
```

Result of `evtest` command for <kbd>CE</kbd> and <kbd>Del</kbd> keys:

```
^[[3~Event: time 1641717606.383528, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value d3
Event: time 1641717606.383528, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 111 (KEY_DELETE), value 0
Event: time 1641717606.383528, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
```

Is there any workaround to this problem? I want to map <kbd>CE</kbd> key to <kbd>End</kbd> but I do not want <kbd>Del</kbd> to be mapped to <kbd>End</kbd> also.