# How to remap two keys that have the same scan code

Tags: laptop, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, computer-architecture

I recently bought a Dell G15 5520, and it has a few redundant/useless keys. Above the number pad, it has a dedicated Calulator key, a Clear Key (delete), and a +/- key (f9). The regular f9 key came mapped as f17 which turns on or off a gaming mode setting.

I was trying to remap these three keys using Microsoft powertoys, and I was able to remap the calculator key and the +/- key; however, when I tried to map the "CE" key, it changes the function of both the CE key and the delete key above the backspace.

Sharpkey and KeyboardKeyInfo both indicate that "CE" and "Delete" have the same scan code.

I found the following two examples of people asking similar questions; however, no solutions were able to be provided:

https://www.reddit.com/r/AutoHotkey/comments/sgfj7b/does_ahk_support_calculator_keys_above_numpad_in/

[Assign different keycodes for two keys with same keycode](https://superuser.com/questions/1698268/assign-different-keycodes-for-two-keys-with-same-keycode)

Comment: If they have the same scan code then what you want is impossible.

Comment: Actually i'm not sure if it is the scancode or the keycode. I will modify my question to reflect this. I will check soon I need to wait till i'm home, and will have to research how to determine what is happening.

Comment: @DavidPostill I used a couple of free utilities to check the scan code, and they are indeed the same. Is it really impossible? if so, it's ridiculous that they would make a keyboard that has the same two keys hardwired to be identical. >:(